# ng-repeat an array of names in an object, but not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, controller

I am passing in data on my controller and it is working. The data is returning as an array of objects. I set the data on a $scope which I would like to run ng-repeat on. Not only ng-repeating is not working, but I am not getting any errors. Please advice.

**html view**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title" ng-repeat='state in states'>{{state.name}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>
```

**angular controller**

```
app.controller('rankingsCtrl', function($scope, rankingsService) { //Start Controller

    // ***********************************************
    // *************** GET LATEST DATA ***************
    // ***********************************************  
    var getAllStateRankings = function() {
        rankingsService.getStateRankingsData().then(function(data) {
            console.log("Contoller Data", data);

            $scope.states = [{
                name: data.state
            }];
        });
    };
    getAllStateRankings();
```

**json data**
[image]

Comment: can you post the json that prints to console on your `console.log`?  Your code suggests that the data returned is one single state...

Comment: 0: Object
__v: 0
_id: "55dd37fbecffb137944b2068"
accessToCapital: 23
business: 23
costOfLiving: 32
economy: 5
education: 2
infrastructure: 9
overall: 1
qualityOfLife: 3
state: "Minnesota"
technologyAndInnovation: 6
workforce: 13

@StaffordWilliams

Comment: Try adding that in your question with code formatting, rather than in a comment.  The javascript looks right... how are you attaching your controller to the html?

Comment: I added an image. Through ui-router. On my app.js I defined my controller for the view. I tested it out of everything was linked properly and it is. However, ng-repeat/controller is not working. @StaffordWilliams

Comment: Regarding the console log why don't you simply set `$scope.states = data`? Plus in the console log, there is no `name` for a state. So you should print `{{state.state}}` in your template.

Comment: @c4k I can try that. I wanted to manipulate my data in controller to keep my code clean.

Comment: @MihirPatel `state.name` property does not exist.

Comment: the way you have it you're creating an array of one object, when what is returned by the data is an array of multiple objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do this:

```
$scope.states = data;
```

Then, the following snippet should work properly.

```
<h3 class="panel-title" ng-repeat='state in states'>{{state.state}}</h3>
```

Comment: There is no `name` property for a record in `data`. And why would one loop in an array to create a new one ? The "simply like this" alternative is better.

Comment: Don't forget to change `state.name` by `state.state` (or rename better the variable in the `ng-repeat`)